# Overflow error of dividing two columns of crosstab query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a qrosstab query to find the percentage of the passed students in each class and subject. The qrosstab query that I have includes three columns namely :

```
Class (Row heading) 
subject (Column heading)
Percentage: (Value)
```

The percentage field has the following expression:

```
Percentage:(Count(IIf([Total]>49,1,Null))/Count((IIf([Total]>0,1,Null)))*100
```

I got error "overflow", however, it works when I use the following expression:

```
Percentage: (Count(IIf([Total]>49,1,Null))/Count([Total]))*100
```

Any help please ?

Note:
[Total] >49 means the student is passed,while [Total] >0 means discard the students who has no mark out of the percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Sum:

```
Percentage: Sum(Abs([Total]>49))/Sum(Abs([Total]>0))*100
```

Comment: Then double-check your values.

Comment: Null values, or if you divide by zero.